# Blade file return the code only

Tags: laravel-5

The blade file is like this index.blade.php

```
@foreach ( $users as $user ) 

    <li>{ !! $user['first_name']!! } { !! $user['last_name']!! } from { !! $user['location']!! }</li>

@endforeach
```

The controller is UsersController and the code is like

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $users = [
            0 => [
                'first_name' => 'Ranjit',
                'last_name'  => 'Pradhan',
                'location'   => 'Bhubaneswar'
            ],
            1 => [
                'first_name' => 'Rojalin',
                'last_name'  => 'Pradhan',
                'location'   => 'Angul'
            ]
        ];

        return view( 'admin.users.index', compact('users') );       
    }
}
```

and the web.php file is like this

```
Route::get( 'users', [ 'uses' => 'UsersController@index'] );
```

But i cant get the result like an li, but it is returning the code of blade file.

```
{ !! $user['first_name']!! } { !! $user['last_name']!! } from { !! $user['location']!! }
{ !! $user['first_name']!! } { !! $user['last_name']!! } from { !! $user['location']!! }
```

where is the problem ? did i do any mistake ? I am learner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Blade syntax is not valid. Remove the spaces between `{` and `!!`.

```
<li>{{ $user['first_name'] }} {{ $user['last_name'] }} from {{ $user['location'] }}</li>
```

And `{!!  !!}` is meant for unescaped content, e.g. HTML. You should use `{{  }}` the vast majority of the time so that HTML entities are properly escaped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I know it is a silly mistake.